# Regular expression extract filename from line content

Tags: regex

I'm very new to regular expression. I want to extract the following string 
"109_Admin_RegistrationResponse_20130103.txt"

from this file content, the contents is selected per line: 
01-10-13  10:44AM                   47 107_Admin_RegistrationDetail_20130111.txt 
01-10-13  10:40AM                   11 107_Admin_RegistrationResponse_20130111.txt

The regular expression should not pick the second line, only the first line should return a true.

Comment: if the input is that line, how about `[^\s]*$`?

Comment: what is your programming language ?

Comment: The answer Luiges90 provided seems correct, I just realized that I need to include the phrase "RegistrationDetail" on the regular expression just as indicated on the example above, so that it only picks those file names with that phrase.

Answer (score 3):

Your Regex has a lot of different mistakes...

1. Your line does not start with your required filename but you put an `^` there
2. missing `+` in your character group `[a-zA-Z]`, hence only able to match a single character
3. does not include `_` in your character group, hence it won't match `Admin_RegistrationResponse`
4. missing `\` and `d{2}` would match `dd` only.
5. As per M42's answer (which I left out), you also need to escape your dot `.` too, or it would match `123_abc_12345678atxt` too (notice the `a` before `txt`)

Your regex should be

`\d+_[a-zA-Z_]+_\d{4}\d{2}\d{2}\.txt$`

which can be simplified as

`\d+_[a-zA-Z_]+_\d{8}\.txt$`

as `\d{2}\d{2}` really look redundant -- unless you want to do with capturing groups, then you would do:

`\d+_[a-zA-Z_]+_(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})\.txt$`

Comment: The answer you provided seems correct, I just realized that I need to include the phrase "RegistrationDetail" on the regular expression just as indicated on the example above, so that it only picks those file names with that phrases.

Comment: I got it, thanks for the help. \d+_[a-zA-Z_]+_[RegistrationDetail]+_\d{8}.txt$

Comment: Well, you don't put `RegistrationDetail` in the character group - you are not going to match any string that contains any character in `[RegistrationDetail]`, or, literally, `[aegilnorstRD]`... I think you want `\d+_[a-zA-Z_]+_RegistrationDetail_\d{8}.txt$` instead

Answer (score 1):

Remove the anchors and escape the dot:

```
\d+[a-zA-Z_]+\d{8}\.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a newbie in php but i think you can use `explode()` function in php or any equivalent in your language.

```
$string = "01-09-13 10:17AM 11 109_Admin_RegistrationResponse_20130103.txt";
$pieces = explode("_", $string);

$stringout = "";
foreach($i = 0;$i<count($pieces);i++){
 $stringout = $stringout.$pieces[$i];
}
```